# Control multiple tab-contents with one nav-tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a regular [Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) tab. What I want to do is to control is to control multiple
 `tab-content` container with one `nav-tabs` element.

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju9sV/4/)

In this example, when I change tabs, only first one is changed. I want for both containers to change, not just first one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here I update your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju9sV/6/)

I add the **data-target** attribute to a-elements and change ids in second tab-content

I modified this lines,

Yours:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">C1</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">C2</a>  </li>
```

My update:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#home" data-target="#home, #home_else" data-toggle="tab">C1</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile" data-target="#profile, #profile_else" data-toggle="tab">C2</a>  </li>
```

And the second tab-content, Yours:

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
        <p>Content 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
        <p>Content 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My update:

```
<div id="myTabContent2" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home_else">
        <p>Content 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile_else">
        <p>Content 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any solution for Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 18):

You should just use a class instead. I just was working on Bootstrap 3 tabbed content inside a modal window. Was trying to get the modal window to open to the correct tab, but I needed two tabs to open, one for the modal header, and one for the content, with extra nab tabs in the footer.

I used a class and it worked. So, change `<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">` to `<div class="tab-pane fade in active home">` and `<a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">` to `<a href=".home" data-toggle="tab">` ... worked for me.

Comment: This is simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique.

Read 
[Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

problem with your code

> Two elements with id home , profile and myTabContent.

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
        <p>Content 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
        <p>Content 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
        <p>Content 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
        <p>Content 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and
you are giving `href="#home"` which will target the first element with id.Not all elements with id.

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">C1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">C2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hm.. yeah I know that ID are supposed to be unique, it's just that even if i change ids to classes it's still not working for me. Care to give me an example. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. The example above though is from documentation.

Answer (score 0):

"data-target" is don't work Bootstrap4.

This is Bootstrap4 version.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#home, #home_else" aria-selected="true" id="home_tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#profile, #profile_else" aria-selected="false" id="profile_tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#messages, #messages_else" aria-selected="false" id="messages_tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#settings, #settings_else" aria-selected="false" id="settings_tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" aria-labelledby="home_tab" role="tabpanel">...1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" aria-labelledby="profile_tab" role="tabpanel">...2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" aria-labelledby="messages_tab" role="tabpanel">...3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" aria-labelledby="settings_tab" role="tabpanel">...4</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home_else" aria-labelledby="home_tab">...11</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile_else" aria-labelledby="profile_tab">...22</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages_else" aria-labelledby="messages_tab">...33</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings_else" aria-labelledby="settings_tab">...44</div>
  </div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      var activated_tab = e.target // activated tab
      var previous_tab = e.relatedTarget // previous tab
      if(activated_tab.id === 'home_tab') {
        $('#home_else').css('display', 'block');
        $('#profile_else').css('display', 'none');
        $('#messages_else').css('display', 'none');
        $('#settings_else').css('display', 'none');
      };
      if(activated_tab.id === 'profile_tab') {
        $('#home_else').css('display', 'none');
        $('#profile_else').css('display', 'block');
        $('#messages_else').css('display', 'none');
        $('#settings_else').css('display', 'none');
      }
      if(activated_tab.id === 'messages_tab') {
        $('#home_else').css('display', 'none');
        $('#profile_else').css('display', 'none');
        $('#messages_else').css('display', 'block');
        $('#settings_else').css('display', 'none');
      }
      if(activated_tab.id === 'settings_tab') {
        $('#home_else').css('display', 'none');
        $('#profile_else').css('display', 'none');
        $('#messages_else').css('display', 'none');
        $('#settings_else').css('display', 'block');
      }
      // 処理,,,,,
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```