# materialize control multiple tab-contents with one nav-tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, materialize

My problem is quite similar with this one: [Control multiple tab-contents with one nav-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719653/control-multiple-tab-contents-with-one-nav-tabs)

Just like the one in that question, I want to change the container of two id with one tab click. The difference is I'm using materialize CSS.

here's my html :

```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Test 3</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col s12">
      <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
      <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
      <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
      <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div id="test1a" class="col s12">Test 1A</div>
      <div id="test2a" class="col s12">Test 2A</div>
      <div id="test3a" class="col s12">Test 3A</div>
      <div id="test4a" class="col s12">Test 4A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here's the fiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nugiigun/v6j8dvy4/3/)

When I click TEST1, I want the content to be TEST1 and TEST1A. etc.

Thanks!

Comment: use the event api of the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below html

```
HTML CODE:
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1,#test1a">Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2,#test2a">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3,#test3a">Disabled Tab</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4,#test4a">Test 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
          <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
          <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
          <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <div id="test1a" class="col s12">Test 1A</div>
          <div id="test2a" class="col s12">Test 2A</div>
          <div id="test3a" class="col s12">Test 3A</div>
          <div id="test4a" class="col s12">Test 4A</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that a href can target more than one ID