# Bootstrap: How to display 2 tab-contents by clicking on a single tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tabs

I have a page with 2 tabs.

I want the `pills-public` tab to display :

- PUBLIC BLOCK 1

I want the `pills-private` tab to display :

- PRIVATE BLOCK 2
- PRIVATE BLOCK 1

Note that the 2 PRIVATE content are not in the same region.

How to do this ? The code below does not work...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-public-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-public" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-public" aria-selected="false">PUBLIC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-private-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-private" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-private" aria-selected="true">PRIVATE</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="region-top">
  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-private" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-private-tab">PRIVATE BLOCK 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="region-bottom">
  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-public" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-public-tab">PUBLIC BLOCK 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-private" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-private-tab">PRIVATE BLOCK 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Bootstrap 4: Control multiple tab panels with single tab nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386330/bootstrap-4-control-multiple-tab-panels-with-single-tab-nav).

Comment: @showdev Thank you but I'm looking for an example with my code and the link you put date of 8 months.

Comment: The post seems to indicate that it's not possible in Bootstrap 4 without writing your own JavaScript code; that is, unless a pull request has since been merged. The last activity I see is that changes were requested, so I don't think a solution has been merged. But I could be wrong. Also, you can apparently use the collapse component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple HTML elements with similar IDs... if you do, only the first one will be picked - we add our custom classes `pillsPrivateClass` and `pillsPublicClass` to get around this; `class="tab-content"` should be used in the code only once; with bootstrap 4 (out of the box) even after re-arranging the elements like i did, 2 tabs wouldn't get toggled with a single click.. so we'd have to use jQuery to toggle/un-toggle any additional divs...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-link").click(function() {
    if ($(this)[0].id == 'pills-private-tab') {
      $(".pillsPrivateClass").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) { /* */ } else {
          $(this).addClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('show');
        }
      });
      $(".pillsPublicClass").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
          $(this).removeClass('show');
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(".pillsPrivateClass").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
          $(this).removeClass('show');
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.pillsPrivateClass:not(.active) {
  display: none
}

.pillsPublicClass:not(.active) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-public-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-public" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-public" aria-selected="false">PUBLIC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link " id="pills-private-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-private" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-private" aria-selected="false">PRIVATE</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class='region-top'>
    <div id="pills-private" class=" tab-pane  pillsPrivateClass" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-private-tab">
      PRIVATE BLOCK 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='region-bottom'>
    <div id="pills-public" class=" tab-pane  pillsPublicClass" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-private-tab">
      PUBLIC BLOCK 1
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="pills-private" class=" tab-pane  pillsPrivateClass" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-private-tab">
      PRIVATE BLOCK 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Super thank you I confirm that it works. I tested with Bootstrap 3 and 4 and it works for both versions.